# $injector:undef Provider 'dataService' must return a value from $get factory method

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS. Whdile I was following the instructor, I wrote the same code as he did. But I am getting a `[$injector:undef] Provider 'dataService' must return a value from $get factory method` error. When I searched for this error in web, it is told that I must return a function or an object. I guess I am doing it. My factory declaration is below:

```
module.factory("dataService", ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var _topics = [];
    var _getTopics = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get("/api/v1/topics?includeReplies=true")
            .then(function (result) {
                //success
                angular.copy(result.data, _topics);
                deferred.resolve();
            },
            function () {
                //error         
                deferred.reject();
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    return
    {
        topics: _topics;
        getTopics: _getTopics;
    };
}]);
```

Any helps are appreciated...

Comment: @wayne-ellery it doesn't help anyone if you fix the question.

Comment: @PeterJ.Hart Sorry. I did it by mistake. I've reverted it back to the original question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a syntax error in you code in the return statement. You should use a comma to separate the properties of the object. It should be:

```
return {
    topics: _topics,
    getTopics: _getTopics
};
```

---

Based on the comment thread, the ultimate solution appears to have been removing the line break between `return` and `{`. See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27738985/1264804) for more explanation.

Comment: I tried this before. It gives me the below error `Critical error was detected at line 35, column 18 in http://localhost:50272/js/home-index.js.
SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'
Unhandled exception at line 4117, column 9 in http://localhost:50272/Scripts/angular.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module homeIndex due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'homeIndex' is not available!`

Comment: Please post what's on the line. You should be able to click on it.

Comment: It is exactly on the "," on the code `return
    {
        topics: _topics,
        getTopics: _getTopics
    };`

Comment: Ignore my edit. Try moving the starting brace up onto the return line.

Comment: Syntax is definitely correct: http://plnkr.co/edit/D3a53Jg3T0iyURWQJ3aW?p=preview

Comment: Is that fixed now. If so please mark my answer as correct. And can you please change your question back to what it was before.

Comment: you are right. The syntax was wrong. The second one is the ";". But the first one is the flower bracket after return. It should be on the same line. Go to your plunker and press "enter" between return and {. Thanks for the helps