# Provider 'xx' must return a value from $get factory method in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written an `angularjs` factory as below

```
module.factory('LogService', function () {

    function log(msg) {
        console.log("Rahkaran:" + new Date() + "::" + msg);
    }

    return 
    {
        log: log
    };

});
```

But I kept getting this error

> `Provider 'LogService' must return a value from $get factory method`

I googled about the error and I couldn't find any solution.

Coincidentally I changed the `return` statement to this

```
return{
    log: log
};
```

And error is gone!!

Is there any differences between having `{` in front of `return` or at the next line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is called **Automatic semicolon insertion**

The return statement is affected by automatic semicolon insertion (ASI). There is no line terminator `;` between the return keyword and the expression allowed.

```
return
a + b;

// is transformed by ASI into

return; 
a + b;
```

So you must insert  `{` in front of return and **Not at the next line.**

*Reference:* 
*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return*

Answer (score 1):

In your case there will be always a non-undefined value returned.
But in other cases the issue might be also that you do return null or undefined value from the factory.