# throw syntax in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How is

```
    throw
       {
         name: 'type error',
         message: 'provide numeric value'
       };
```

a incorrect syntax when

```
    throw{
         name: 'type error',
         message: 'provide numeric value'
       };
```

Is a correct syntax?

Is it really necessary to attach curly bracket with throw and why?

Comment: The console says it clearly in chrome: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal newline after throw* It is the line break that is the problem. Add a space and it would work `throw {` It does not have to be attached.

Comment: the same thing `return` statement is also affected.. Its **Automatic semicolon insertion**. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27738985/3556874

Comment: @epascarello please read the question once again, I don't think you are getting me.The space given or not given doesn't matter,what matters is that the { should be in the same line. The { bracked attached together works perfectly.

Comment: I know what the problem is.... The error message that chrome gives was the answer. And there a few things in JS that can not have a line break after them. You found one of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, a semicolon is always [inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi/2846298#2846298) after a lone `throw` keyword even though you can't legally have a `throw` statement by itself, so what you get is this:

```
    throw;
       {
         name: 'type error',
         message: 'provide numeric value'
       };
```

which results in a syntax error.

For what it's worth, C# (which, like JS, is also based on an ECMA standard) does support `throw;` statements as a way to [rethrow an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623/throwing-exceptions-best-practices/22628#22628). Perhaps they're futureproofing ECMAScript for support for a similar feature down the road. But this is just conjecture on my part.